# Save ListView positions on add

Tags: java, android

So I have a problem, I have a Array named testes, that has some positions and I use those positions to get the ID of the parcel that im clicking . But when I use search those positions change can't I store the position that they were originally ? Here is the code:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_list);

    testList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.testList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new Test_row_adapter(TestList.this,testes);




    testList.setAdapter(adapter);


    testList.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {




                    int ID_WANTED=myDB.getAllIds().get(i);

                        Intent i2 = new Intent(TestList.this,TesteInfoDisplay.class);


                        String DateClickedDisciplina = myDB.getDisciplina(ID_WANTED);
                    String DateClickedSala = myDB.getSala(ID_WANTED);
                    String DateClickedDia = myDB.getDates(ID_WANTED);
                    String DateClickedHora = myDB.getHour(ID_WANTED);



                    i2.putExtra("dateID", ID_WANTED);
                    i2.putExtra("returnedData", DateClickedDia);
                    i2.putExtra("returnedHour", DateClickedHora);
                    i2.putExtra("returnedDisciplina", DateClickedDisciplina);
                    i2.putExtra("returnedSala", DateClickedSala);

                        startActivity(i2);

                    }

            }
    );
}

public static void RestartArray(){
   DataBaseHelper myDB = CustomApplication.getDatabaseHelper();
    for(int digg=1; contador2<=myDB.getHowMany(); contador2++) {



                int ID_WANTED = myDB.getAllIds().get(contador2 - 1);

                testes.add("Data:  " + myDB.getDates(ID_WANTED) + "        " + myDB.getHour(ID_WANTED) + "\n" + "Discilpina:  " + myDB.getDisciplina(ID_WANTED));
    }


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(
            new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                    ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(String temp : testes){
                        if(temp.toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())){
                            tempList.add(temp);
                        }
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new Test_row_adapter(TestList.this,tempList);
                        testList.setAdapter(adapter);


                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
    );


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

}

I want to store the positions they were in before the search was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the list view with the temporary search list.

So your original list is not modified. Thus whenever you click on the row after searching, get the Text in the selected row and search the index of the text in the "testes" list. This will give you the position of the text in the actual list view.

Whenever you use array adapter the default layout of Android is used to populate each row in list view. Please use the below code to get the text on item click method.

TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
String text = textView.getText().toString();

Comment: So in position it should be the original position ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question. But you do not have to worry about the position of text in the list. 

All you have to do is after searching, when you click on the item in list, get the text from the list(I've already mentioned how to get the text from clicked position in Listview)
and search the position of the text in the actual list "testes". 

This way you can know what is the position of the text in the actual ListView.